# In MVC whats best practice for placing primary key in table row

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller

My question is, what's best practice when placing a primary key on table row & using Jquery to find the ID.

So using MVC, you create table of data with edit & delete button which will open model popup when clicked.

Should you:

a) Place Primary key in data-attribute for each button

b) Have hidden field on each row

c) On each button use Onclick & passes ID to function

d) Have ID on tr tag

Comment: Never on IDs. If it is just for use by jQuery, I tend to use a `data-id=""` once on each row.

Comment: I guess anywhere that you can access the ID would work.  A hidden field is pretty common, since it automatically posts with a form as well.  Data attributes are sensible too for JavaScript work.  (Note that the two aren't mutually exclusive.)  This really doesn't have anything to do with the MVC pattern, it's just about putting a data element in an HTML table.

Comment: It really depends on the situation. For example, in some situations I have name="object[id]" and in others I use a hidden field. It really depends on what you are building IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- a) Do not repeat attributes if you do not need to (it bloats the page)
- b) Hidden fields are only good if you need the value posted back
- c) Never use `onclick` handlers with jQuery (it separates the handler from the code for no good reason and it only supports a single handler)
- d) Never use IDs for data attributes (too much chance of a clash as IDs must be *unique* on a page)

so I tend to go with option `e)`:

- e) If it is just for use by jQuery, I tend to use a `data-id=""` once on each row.

Then from any element in the row I use `.closest('tr').data("id")` etc to get the PK. (actually I use this pattern so often I have a custom jQuery extension to do this in one. e.g.: `.closestAttr("data-id")`).

**.closestAttr():**

TypeScript code provided for anyone interested:

```
// Find the nearest matching attribute in the elements themselves, as well as in all ancestors
jQuery.fn.closestAttr = function (attribute: string): string
{
    return this.closest('[' + attribute + ']').attr(attribute);
};
```

or in plain JS:

```
// Find the nearest matching attribute in the elements themselves, as well as in all ancestors
jQuery.fn.closestAttr = function (attribute)
{
    return this.closest('[' + attribute + ']').attr(attribute);
};
```

Additional Note: If the data is grouped under a parent, I then have another `data-id=""` on the table representing the parent FK/group etc.

**Update - For the code example provided in comment:**

I would do it this way:

```
@foreach (var i in n) 
{ 
    <tr data-id="@i">
        <td>@i</td>
        <td><input type="button" class="edit" value="Edit" /></td> 
        <td><input type="button" class="delete" value="Delete" /></td> 
    </tr> 
}
```

and fetch the id via `.closest('tr').data("id")` from the button pressed.

Comment: Hi TrueBlueAussie, where would you place data-id if row has two buttons? tr?

Comment: Sample: 
                    @foreach (var i in n)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@i</td>
                            <td><input type="button" class="edit" data-id="@i" value="Edit" /></td>
                            <td><input type="button" class="delete" data-id="@i" value="Delete" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    }

Comment: @Chris: just use `@foreach (var i in n) { <tr data-id="@i">` and the `closest` code shown above to get the PK/id).

Comment: Thanks this what I wanted to no.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in a true code-first situation, it is always best to have a unique column devoted to primary key.  I assume in your questions you are equating columns with buttons in Jquery.  That just works the best.

Of course, if you are using a pre-existing table, one must use the keys one has in that table.  Sometimes they are complex keys using more than one column; I've even seen one table where all the columns were used to form a key (but this is very poor design IMHO).

If you are in charge of the database design, reserving a column for primary key is always worth it in my point of view, especially if you are using SQL server.